# Check if php file is called by ajax or xhr

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to check if php file(myphpfile.php) is called by ajax or xhr in my myphpfile.php ? I dont have any code to show. It is generic Question. I am using localhost(xampp). I am using Jquery.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    //ajax detected
}
```

> https://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Comment: not working... `if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    //ajax detected
}else{}`. Only else condition is working..

Comment: It also depends on the javascript framework you are using, if the framework is Jquery it does send the header HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH so above code will work fine. Also it would not work on IE7. which framework are you using ?

Comment: can you show me some code to know how you are calling the page ?

Comment: var request = new XMLHttpRequest();request.open('post', 'phpfiles/albumuploader.php');
   request.send(data); where data is of form data;var data = new FormDat(formid[0]);

Answer (score 0):

I'd just go with this:

```
if( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === null )
{
    // not ajax
}
else
{
   // ajax
}
```

**tested on:** IE 11, Firefox 43, Chrome 50